# ¿Qué palabra se usa para describir a alguien que suda mucho?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

¿Qué palabra es adecuada para describir a una persona que suda mucho?

Comment: Tenemos la misma duda con un amigo y hemos hecho una apuesta!!! yo creo que la palabra correcta es Sudor debido al proceso químico y por las glándulas sudoriparas!! en cambio, mi amigo dice que la palabra correcta es transpirar!!! Ambas palabras creo que tienen un significado correcto, pero la forma correcta para referirse a la sudororación de una persona es "sudor", no transpirar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La palabra es **[sudoroso](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=sudoroso&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE)**:

> **sudoroso, sa.**
>   *1. adj.* Que está sudando mucho.
>   *2. adj.* Muy propenso a sudar.

Answer (score 3):

Es una cuestión de uno tener más vocabulario que su vecino, eso se nota en todos los países y todas las lenguas.

Primeramente,

```
Los caballos sudan (animales).    
Los hombres transpiran (ser humano).
```

Entonces, los caballos son muy sudorosos y los hombres pueden ser también muy transpiradores.  ¿No se dice que el que conspira es un conspirador? Entonces el que transpira es lógicamente un transpirador y no sudoroso.

Nota: No soy de lengua castellana, pero portuguesa de Brasil.

Comment: Me gustó tu respuesta! jaja, tal vez me marquen como spam pero me parece muy interesante que comentes eso porque me deja ver que en el portugués sudar es sólo para animales, a diferencia de el español donde transpirar suena más formal y educado, no dudo que con el tiempo transpirar reemplace a sudar pero para eso falta mucho tiempo. Definitivamente es natural que el vecino tenga palabras diferentes, nada más cambiando de región dentro de un mismo país o aunque el vecino hable español ya hay nuevas palabras. xD Saludos.

Comment: Se te nota que no eres hispanohablante nativo, al decir `No soy de lengua castellana, pero portuguesa de Brasil.` que jamás diría así un hispanohablante nativo y porque en español las personas `sudan` también aunque en portugués el uso de dicho verbo sea exclusivo para animales. No creo que transpirar reemplace en el futuro a sudar, son sinónimos, si bien transpirar tiene una connotación más formal. La gente sigue diciendo sudar sin pudor alguno.

Answer (score 2):

"Sudoroso/a" es el único adjectivo correcto que se me ocurre, pero en mi experiencia (Argentina) la palabra es *muy* poco usada.

> "Juan suda (o transpira) mucho"

es mucho más común, y a mis oídos suena más natural, que

> "Fulano es sudoroso".

Comment: Pues es que nadie diría (creo yo) que _fulano es sudoroso_ lo mas común es decir _fulano suda mucho_, pero si es común, al menos en México, decir que _flulano **está** muy sudoroso_ sobre todo si uno acaba de hacer ejercicio o vive en una región calurosa (como en el 80 % del país).